# How can I get all loaded classes together with their methods?

Tags: php

As known, php returns with "get_declared_clasess()" us the list of all the classes used on the runtime.

But I want the methods to be returned together with the classes that are used.

For example ; get_declared_clasess()

```
<?php 

[
256 => "App\Mobi\V1\Optional\Repository\Sms\SmsAdapter"
  257 => "App\Mobi\V1\Optional\Repository\Sms\Source\Ttnet\SmsTtnet"
]

?>
```

It returns like this but I do not know which method is used with this method.

get_declared_functions() does not work like I want.

How to get this?

So the structure I want to returned is as follows;

```
<?php 

    [
    256 => "App\Mobi\V1\Optional\Repository\Sms\SmsAdapter::get"
      257 => "App\Mobi\V1\Optional\Repository\Sms\Source\Ttnet\SmsTtnet::get"
    ]

    ?>
```

Comment: do you need this at runtime (I doubt that's possible) or would a php documentator help you out?

Comment: I need that because so; I can do something like event when a class is loaded.

Comment: _"do something like event"_ - I'm afraid it's still not clear what you want to achieve.